# Paypal API - Modify Recurring Payment Profile

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

We currently handle subscriptions on our site via Paypal with the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API. This created a monthly subscription for 7.99 a month. We would like to launch an offer where the user could change that monthly subscription for an annual subscription which would be much more convenient.

I looked into the APIs and found the UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API. I tested it and found that I could change the amount charged monthly, say from 7.99 to 5.99. However I can find no request field to change the period from Month to Year.

Is there a way to accomplish this with the UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API. Or would the profile necessarily be cancelled and a new one created from scratch?

Comment: any progress? I am also facing the same issue, what did you do please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a limitation, you can change amounts but not plans, you need to cancel and create a new one.

Comment: have you tried with the new subscription rest api https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, paypal has some limitations on UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

So it's better to cancel previous Recurring Payments Profile and create new.

Here is Paypal help for how to Cancel PayPal Recurring Profile using API

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/