# How to add an item_number entry to an existing paypal subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to see if it is possible to add an item_number entry to an existing paypal subscription. I'm working with a service provider that has created subscriptions for clients without providing a way to map their subscription to their account at the service provider's website.

A response to a similar question ([Paypal API - Modify Recurring Payment Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815353/paypal-api-modify-recurring-payment-profile)) suggests that we may need to cancel the existing subscriptions and create new ones. Our case is slightly different, so I'm wanting to see if anyone has any suggestion on how this may be done.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to check their API documentation. Many times they have application scenarios covered. They may also have a developers' network, if you don't get the help you need in the docs then try posting your question on their developers' network or chat if that's an option.